# Selected Node Not Available RC=40

Tags: cobol, mainframe, expeditor

I am new to Mainframe/COBOL and have a question about an error I am receiving when attempting to run my program in XPediter. I get a message after attempting to run my program SELECTED NODE NOT AVAILABLE RC=40. Not sure what this means or what I might have to ask for in my company.

I have gone back through my JCL and checked if everything lined up like program name and what not. Seems good from my point of view but I am also new to this so It might be off.

Answer (score 2):

Jason,

You need to ensure that COBOL program you want to DEBUG is compiled with xpediter.

Here is a sample JCL

```
//***************************************************************
//* Compile the program for Xpediter                            *
//***************************************************************
//COMPILE  EXEC PGM=CWPCMAIN,REGION=4M,COND=(8,LT),              
// PARM=('APOST,MAP,XREF,LIST')                                  
//STEPLIB  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=COMPUWARE.CSS.LOADLIB                 
//         DD DISP=SHR,DSN=Cobol.compile.library                  
//SYSTERM  DD SYSOUT=(*)                                         
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=(*)                                         
//SYSPUNCH DD DUMMY                                              
//SYSUT1   DD UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(2,2))                       
//SYSUT2   DD UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(2,2))                       
//SYSUT3   DD UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(2,2))                       
//SYSUT4   DD UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(2,2))                       
//SYSUT5   DD UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(2,2))                       
//SYSUT6   DD UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(2,2))                       
//SYSLIN   DD UNIT=SYSDA,DISP=(NEW,PASS),                        
//            SPACE=(CYL,(1,1)),DCB=(,BLKSIZE=400)               
//SYSIN    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=YOUR.cobol.source(pgmname)            
//XOPTIONS DD DISP=SHR,DSN=XT.XT70B1.XOPTIONS                    
//CWPDDIO  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=FLGFGR1.COBOL.DDIO                    
//CWPPRMO  DD *                                                  
COBOL(OUTPUT(PRINT,DDIO))                                        
PROCESSOR(OUTPUT(NOPRINT,NODDIO),TEXT(NONE))                     
LANGUAGE(VSCOBOL)                                                
DDIO(OUTPUT(NOLIST,NOXREF,FIND,NODMAP,NOOFFSET,COMPRESS))        
/*                                                               
//***************************************************************
//* Link edit the cobol program                                 *
//***************************************************************
//LINK     EXEC PGM=IEWL,REGION=1M,COND=(8,LE),                  
// PARM=('LIST,LET')                                             
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                           
//SYSLIN   DD DSN=*.COMPILE.SYSLIN,DISP=(SHR,PASS)               
//SYSLIB   DD DSN=Cobol.compile.library,DISP=SHR                 
//SYSLMOD  DD DSN=Your.pgm.LOADLIB(pgmname),DISP=SHR             
//SYSUT1   DD UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,(2,2))                       
//*
```